# How do I get exact fare rate instead of fare estimation using Uber API?

Tags: uber-api

Instead of getting "high_estimate": 11.0 and "low_estimate": 8.0
or "estimate": "$13-17" of using https://api.uber.com/v1.2/estimates/price? is there a way to get exact fare rate as the same as Uber app?

```
{
  "localized_display_name": "uberX",
  "distance": 12.88,
  "display_name": "uberX",
  "product_id": "2143f90b-ce68-4f6d-a113-4872b207e626",
  "high_estimate": 17.0,
  "low_estimate": 13.0,
  "duration": 1800,
  "estimate": "$13-17",
  "currency_code": "USD"
},
```

Answer (score 3):

The feature you are referring to is called "Upfront Fare". It is being rolled out [gradually in cities across the globe](https://newsroom.uber.com/upfront-fares-no-math-and-no-surprises/).

You can see which products are enabled for Upfront Fare by looking at [GET /v1.2/products](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/products-get#response). If `upfront_fare_enabled` is set to true, you can get an upfront fare through [POST /v1.2/requests/estimate](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-estimate-post#example-response-with-upfront-fares) with the enabled product to get a `fare_id`. The `fare_id` can be used to lock down an upfront fare and arrival time for a trip. The `fare_id` expires after two minutes.
Finally, you can request the ride using [POST /requests](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-post) with the `fare_id` returned in the previous step.

You should also read the best practices on Upfront Fares [here](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/api/best-practices#upfront-fares).

Comment: But still Uber app and Upfront Fare feature do not provide the same rate.  sometimes 2 cents sometimes more like 10 cents difference for example Upfront Fare returns $9.91 but Uber app is $9.93.